# mod_rewrite %{REQUEST_URI} redirect domain.com/category to category.domain.com

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect

https://www.example.com/category/ and all of it's subcategories and content to
https://category.example.com

So in the end I got e.g

```
https://category.example.com/subcategory/content=xyz;param=1
```

redirecting from

```
https://www.example.com/category/subcategory/content=xyz;param=1
```

I've tried quite a lot suggestions from other threads here, but got only

```
 https://www.example.com/category/subcategory/content=xyz;param=1
 https://category.example.com/
```

and

```
https://www.example.com/category/subcategory/content=xyz;param=1
https://category.example.com/category/subcategory/content=xyz;param=1
```

working.
I think it's my regex, but I'm not sure. My config is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog /var/log/vgn_rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 5
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !category.example.com$ [NC] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/category/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://category.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Mmh, is /category always /category or is it dynamicly different everytime?

Comment: /category is static. But anything what comes after /category is dynamic

Comment: I edited my awnser

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*)$ https://category.yourwebsite.com/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I think all of my tries has been way to complicated.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !category.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/category(.*)$ https://category.example.com$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Did it finally!
Thanks for your help!